# Add Total Row To Each Worksheet in Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have been using this syntax to add a total row to one worksheet

```
    With ActiveSheet
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
End With
Range("C" & LastRow + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LastRow & "]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":L" & LastRow + 1).FillRight
```

I thought to add it to all worksheets in the workbook, I would just need to add a foreach loop like so

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'code above
Next
```

But that did not fit the bill as since I use `With ActiveSheet` it just adds multiple "Total" rows to the selected worksheet.

How can I add a total row to each worksheet in my workbook?

Comment: Change `With ActiveSheet` to `With ws` in your loop, put the last two lines beginning with `Range` inside the `With` block, and put a `.` in front of them to qualify the reference.

Comment: @Comintern - same result as ActiveSheet, just keeps adding to selected sheet.

Comment: Too quick for me.  See the edit.

Comment: @Comintern - that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I did not tested it. you test the code and let me know if there are errors, i will then work on it -

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

 With ws
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
   Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
End With
ws.Range("C" & LastRow + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LastRow & "]C:R[-1]C)"
ws.Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":L" & LastRow + 1).FillRight

Next
```

Comment: As the comment from @Comintem shows if you move the ws.Rane lines inside the with block and put a "." in front of them the code will execute as desired.

Comment: Yes right. But in your code it is outside the with block. hence i put "ws.". :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that you are activating each worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.activate
'code above
Next
```

should do it.